# Does the conceptual model and respective .edmx file get created automatically when using code first?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have been following the new Steve Sanderson MVC3 framework book from Apress and it seems there's no mention at all of creating the conceptual model/*.edmx file from the underlying database. Just basic entity classes and class deriving from DbContext which maps the entity classes to tables in database. However in the middle of the book he suddenly talks of opening the *.edmx file and updating from the database.

I am not following the books exactly, but rather using it to help implement my own solution. The only real difference in my case is that I attached an *.mdf database instead of creating new one with .dbo extension and that I have more tables and relationships in my database, likewise more entity classes for each table. Things seem to work, but there's no edmx file.

Also it was a bit of a pain in the azz typing up all the entity classes and their respective properties. Is there a tool or something, that can create these POCO's from the database for use with DbContext ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read [Code First: Inside DbContext Initialization](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2011/04/15/code-first-inside-dbcontext-initialization/) to get an idea as to how `DbContext` builds up the model without *.edmx file.

EF team has created [Entity Framework Power Tools CTP1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/05/18/ef-power-tools-ctp1-released.aspx) which can reverse engineer your database to create the entity classes and mappings. You will have to rename some of the navigation property names that are created by the tool because they are not meaningful most of the time.

Comment: And it doesn't properly handle schemes and timestamp fields either... But besides that a nice tool.